# How to get indices of top 2 values of each row in a 2-D numpy array, but with a specific area is excluded?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D array for example:

```
p = np.array([[21,2,3,1,12,13],
             [4,5,6,14,15,16],
             [7,8,9,17,18,19]])
b = np.argpartition(p, np.argmin(p, axis=1))[:, -2:]  
com = np.ones([3,6],dtype=np.int)
com[np.arange(com.shape[0])[:,None],b] = 0
print(com)
```

b is the indices of top 2 values of each row in p:

```
b = [[0 5]
    [4 5]
    [4 5]]
```

com is np.ones matrix, the same size as p, the element whose index is same as b will change to 0.
So the result is :

```
com = [[0 1 1 1 1 0]
      [1 1 1 1 0 0]
      [1 1 1 1 0 0]]
```

Now I have one more constraint :

```
p[0:2,0:2]
```

The numbers in these area should not be considered,
so the result should be:

```
b = [[4 5]
    [4 5]
    [4 5]]
```

How can I do this ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make the last constraint clearer? Why is it the same as the `b` above?

Comment: Also you don't need `argmin` there. It seems you only need `b = np.argpartition(p, [-1,-2], axis=1)[:,-2:]`

Comment: Sorry, a typo there, the b matrix should be different  the result should be : ```b = [[4 5]
    [4 5]
    [4 5]]```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your question is clear. Not sure I understand your constraints. Here's a take:

```
# the data
p = np.array([[21, 2, 3, 1, 12, 13],
             [4, 5, 6, 14, 15, 16],
             [7, 8, 9, 17, 18, 19]])

# not sure if this is what you mean by constraint
# but lets ignore values in first two cols and rows
p[0:2, 0:2] = 0

# return the idx of highest values
b = np.argpartition(p, -2)[:, -2:]
```

Comment: Thank you, RRR. I made a typo there, the corrected result b matrix should be ```b = [[4 5] [4 5] [4 5]]```